# yii2, связь моделей. Убрать лишние запросы, типизация данных при queryAll()

Tags: php, yii2

```
/**
     * Gets query for [[Generation]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getGeneration()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Generations::className(), ['id' => 'generationId']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Make]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getMake()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Makes::className(), ['id' => 'makeId']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Model]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Models::className(), ['id' => 'modelId']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[User]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'userId']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Year0]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getYears()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Years::className(), ['id' => 'yearId']);
    }

/**
     * Створює query, для отримання ПОВНОЇ інформації юзера авто
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getQueryAllInfoUserCars()
    {
        $query = $this::find()
            ->select([
                'user_cars.id as userCarId',
                'user_cars.makeId',
                'user_cars.modelId',
                'user_cars.generationId',
                'user_cars.yearId',
                'user_cars.buyYear',
                'user_cars.color',
                'user_cars.about',
                'user_cars.hold',
                'user_cars.engine',
                'user_cars.volume',
                'user_cars.transmission',
                'user_cars.drive',
                'user_cars.horsepower',
                'user_cars.vin',
                'user_cars.plate',
                'user_cars.carUsername',
                'user_cars.scrapped',
                'user_cars.displacement',
                'makes.id as makeId',
                'makes.name as makeName',
                'models.id as modelId',
                'models.name as modelName',
                'models.defaultName as modelDefaultName',
                'generations.id as generationId',
                'generations.defaultName as generationDefaultName',
                'generations.name as generationName',
                'years.id as yearId',
                'years.name as yearName',
            ])
            ->joinWith('make')
            ->joinWith('model')
            ->joinWith('generation')
            ->joinWith('years');

        return $query;
    }

/**
     * Повертаю ПОВНУ інформацію по автомобілю юзера, якшо юзер - авторизований
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws \yii\db\Exception
     */
    public function getLoggedUserCars()
    {
        $query = $this->getQueryAllInfoUserCars();
        $query->where(['user_cars.userId' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);

        $result = $query->all();

      //TODO do logic
       return $result
    }
```

Я делаю связный запрос к БД, чтобы получить данные. Но в логе я заметил что yii2 автоматически делает лишние запросы которые мне не нужны (joinWith делает мне leftJoin и в select я беру данные которые мне нужны)

`/models/UserCars.php:255 2022-12-06 11:34:08 [::1][][-][profile end][yii\db\Command::query] SELECT * FROM makes WHERE` id `IN (13, 137)`

`UserCars.php:255 2022-12-06 11:34:08 [::1][][-][profile end][yii\db\Command::query] SELECT * FROM models WHERE` id `IN (561, 206)`

Аналогично для generation, years.

Но эти данные я уже получаю в моем запросе `getLoggedUserCars`. Как мне убрать эти лишние 4 запроса?

Если я сделаю `$result->queryCommand->queryAll()` это вернет мне данные, но типизация данные пропадет (а она мне нужна).

Мне нужно чтобы данные которые я получал добавились в модель и была типизация данных.
queryAll убирает всю типизацию данных и это большая проблема для меня.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить проблему как у меня я нашел данный пакет https://github.com/yii2tech/ar-eagerjoin.
Это делает то что нужно.